Quotient map, normality of $X$ implies normality of $Y$
The problem is from Munkres' Topology, in the section on separation axioms. It goes as follows:
Let $p : X \to Y$ be a closed, continuous, surjective map. Show that if $X$ is normal, then so is $Y$.
[Hint: If $U$ is an open set containing $p^{-1}(\{y\})$, show there is a neighborhood $W$ of $y$ such that $p^{-1}(W) \subset U$.]
Here is my attempt:

Take two disjoint closed sets $C$ and $C'$ in $Y$.

Since $p$ is a closed and continuous map, the preimages $p^{-1}(C)$ and $p^{-1}(C')$ are closed and disjoint in $X$.

Since $X$ is normal, we can separate $p^{-1}(C)$ and $p^{-1}(C')$ with disjoint open neighborhoods in $X$.

By the hint, for the open neighborhoods $U$ and $U'$ of $p^{-1}(C)$ and $p^{-1}(C')$ in $X$, we can find neighborhoods $W$ and $W'$ in $Y$ such that $p^{-1}(W) \subset U$ and $p^{-1}(W') \subset U'$. This implies that $p^{-1}(C) \subset p^{-1}(W)$ and $p^{-1}(C') \subset p^{-1}(W')$, ensuring that $C \subset W$ and $C' \subset W'$ in $Y$.


This gives us disjoint open neighborhoods $W$ and $W'$ in $Y$ containing $C$ and $C'$, respectively, thus showing that $Y$ is normal.
Is my reasoning correct? If not, what should I consider?

Your reasoning is correct. However, I would suggest you make step 4 clearer, where you conclude that there are neighborhoods $W$ and $W'$ of $C$ and $C'$ such that $p^{-1}(W) \subseteq U$ and $p^{-1}(W') \subseteq U'$. You should construct them explicitly.
